# Is there a way to get attachment data?

Tags: images, attachments, media

So, I'm no big fan of how WP stores images (image data) and I was hoping there had been made some improvements in version 4.x. But alas no.

When I say image data, I mean `url, title, caption, alt text, description` data that you can update in the media gallery.

`wp_get_attachment_image` only returns a URL with this data
`wp_get_attachment_image_src` only returns url
`get_attached_media( 'image' )` returns some data:

```
  public 'post_content' => string 'This is the description'
  public 'post_title' => string 'This is the title'
  public 'post_excerpt' => string 'This is the caption'
  public 'guid' => string 'http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/test.jpg'
```

After I removed the attachment (and deleted the image), then attached another image, `get_attached_media( 'image' )` returns empty.

So **IS** there any good way of getting image data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget that attachments are just *posts* (though they are native posts and those tend to be a special case).

Thus simply `get_post()` on attachment ID should get you typical post object for it. :) Similarly all API functions that work on posts should work on attachments.

Comment: I know, that's why I don't like how images are stored. But now that you mention it, creating a function that uses `get_post` and return the image data is a the way to go :)